# Port forward logins to the root user

Tags: ssh, remote-server, vnc

Hi I am trying to set up the port forward by following steps

Step1: Start vncserver on the remote machine

```
sudo vncserver -geometry 1080x920 -rfbport 5950 -desktop ratewalamit:50
```

Step2:Then I forward the port 50 from my local machine using credentials in .ssh/config

```
host office
    hostname <remote-ip-address>
    localforward 5950 localhost:5950
    User ratewalamit
```

Then start the server on my local machine as

```
ssh -N office
```

Step3: I use remmina with "Remmina VNC Plugin" protocol to access my localhost:5950
using below credentials in remmina

```
Server: localhost:5950
Username: ratewalamit
User password: *************
```

After following the above steps, it successfully connects to my remote address. **But** it only gives option of login to the root user of remote server. I want to login "ratewalamit" available (but not shown in login options on the login screen) on the remote server. please remember I set up the Step1 from logged in session with user 'ratewalamit'